# Swift table view return some cells of my dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsdictionary

Hi guys I want to show only 100 cells from my (10k+) records dict. Im trying to do this with return 100, but its giving me error - index out of range and this is normal behavior for this, but I don't know how to make it good as I want.. :(

Problem is, that I want to show only 100cells but I want to search for everyone of dict..
here is my code:

```
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let count = self.items.count
        return 100
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item: Price = items[indexPath.row]

        tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: -1, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.none)

        showLargePhoto(price: item)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CatalystItem", for: indexPath) as! CatalystTableViewCell
        let item: Price = items[indexPath.row]
        let appSettings: AppSettings = AppSettings()

        cell.lpLabel.text = String(item.no)
        cell.catCermaicValueLabel.text = "\(item.ceramWeight) kg"

        if appSettings.getHideMetalWeights() == false {
            cell.catPtValueLabel.text = item.viewPt ?? ""
            cell.catPdValueLabel.text = item.viewPd ?? ""
            cell.catRhValueLabel.text = item.viewRh ?? ""
        }
        else {
            cell.catPtValueLabel.text = ""
            cell.catPdValueLabel.text = ""
            cell.catRhValueLabel.text = ""
        }

        cell.textCategoryLabel?.text = item.group ?? ""

if FileUtilities.fileExists(nridasnString+".jpg") {
            let image: UIImage? = UIImage(named: tmbLocalPath.path)
            let scaledImage: UIImage? = image?.scaleToWidth(width: 100)

            if cell.imageView != nil {
                cell.imageView!.removeFromSuperview()

                let iv: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 40, width: 100, height: 75))
                iv.image = scaledImage
                iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

                cell.addSubview(iv)
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
```

and I don't know how to make it... kill me please but Im done with it..

Comment: This error indicates that you try to access an element which is outside of the range of available elements in the array. Are you sure you can access the element in the items array?

Comment: when you getting `index out of range` exception? on cell selection or cell loading?

Comment: Are you sure your data has 100+ values ?

Comment: Yea im sure :) I have an answer. Very good, thanks!

Comment: You should NOT remove the original question. Others might have the same problem and find the question useful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let count = self.items.count
    return 100
}
```

with

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
    return min(100,self.items.count)
}
```

Comment: Thanks you men, its work :) I don't believe in myself - that was soo easy... :P

Answer (score 0):

When you return 100 cells but you don't have 100 elements you get a classic "array out of items" "out of bounds".

**You should be aware of this and check that you have indeed enough data to fill those cells or either reduce the number of cells.**

Please replace the current delegate method **numberOfRowsInSection**:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let count = self.items.count
    return 100
}
```

by

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { 
    return min(100,self.items.count)
}
```

You have a nice day and Welcome!